# Power BI - Filter table using slicer to match within concatenated column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've looked all over and can't find a way to do this.

In the table, I have all postcodes throughout the UK and a calculated column that concatenates from another table the products' that have been purchased in that location.

I need to filter the table to **hide rows** where the value selected in the slicer is in the concatenated column. I think this needs to be a measure and have tried using `CONTAINSSTRING` but nothing seems to be working.

Latest measure that I have tried is:

`=IF(CONTAINSSTRING([Concatenated Values],[Selected Slicer Value]),"Hide","Show")`

Does anyone have any ideas?

Example tables and expected results:

[image: example tables and expected results]

Answer (score 1):

You can link the "another table" (the one with the products (not concatenated) per area) to the Area table.
Just change the filter option to: cross-filter direction: both
Then you can use it in your slicer.

Comment: Thanks but I dont think that will work.
It's being used for a map not a table, and is being used to compare where the product was purchased vs areas in the country where it has not been sold to yet.

Comment: What do you mean, you "think" it doesn't work?  It works 100% sure.

Comment: It needs to hide the selected value on one map and show it on the other.
The table with the products (not concatenated) doesn't show all of the UK postcodes (because it's not been installed everywhere). The table with locations and concatenated shows all UK locations

Answer (score 1):

Follow these below steps to achieve your requirement.

Let-

> Your Slicer Table name: Table1

> Your Details table name: Table2

**Step-1:** Create this following measure in **Table2**

```
show_hide_this_row = 
FIND(
    SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[products]),
    MIN(Table2[products]),
    ,
    0
)
```

**Step-2:** Add visual level filter using measure "show_hide_this_row" as below-

[image]

The output will be as below-

> **This functionality only works perfect when single selection is enabled in your slicer.**

[image]